# Writing a function with two functions as arguments

Tags: function-construction

I am trying to write a function of two functions. A function of one function works as in

```
h[f___, x_, y_] := Integrate[f, x]  
h[x^2 + y, x, y]
```

and this function of two functions also works

```
h[f___, g___, x_, y_] := f + g  
h[x^2 + y, x^3, x, y]
```

however, this does not work

```
h[f___, g___, x_, y_] := Integrate[f, x]  
h[x^2 + y, x^3, x, y]
```

Returning the error msg: "Integrate::argmu: Integrate called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected"

Comment: It is not clear to me why you are using `___` ([`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html)) at all.  It may be simply a misunderstanding, and you can use `_` ([`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)) instead.  Or do you need some kind of optional argument behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you are using `___` instead of `_`. `___` is a pattern-matcher which can match zero or more sequences of arguments. In this example, it parses as follows: `f = Null, g = Sequence[x^2 + y, x^3], x = x, y = y`.

This can be prevented if you use `_` instead of `___` throughout.